# Get value from Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, series, getvalue

I was working with some Temperature Data with *Pandas*.

From a *DataFrame* called '**data**' i got the first data observation thanks this line of code:

```
first_obs = data['DATE'][0]
```

Keep in mind that data['DATE'] is a pandas.*Series* object.
data indexes: STATION   ELEVATION   LATITUDE    LONGITUDE   DATE    PRCP    TAVG    TMAX    TMIN    YEAR    MONTH

After some data manipulation i created a new *DataFrame* '**monthly_data**' with these indexes: MONTH   TAVG    YEAR    temp_celsius    ref_temp    diff    abs_diff

Now i wanted to get the row of this dataframe with the maximum value in the 'abs_diff' column:

```
weather_anomaly = monthly_data.loc[monthly_data['abs_diff'] == monthly_data['abs_diff'].max()]
```

Now weather_anomaly is another *DataFrame* Object so now the strange problem comes up:
If i write the code as before like this:

```
weather_anomaly['MONTH'][0]
```

an error comes up:

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py
> in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    3079             try:
> -> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)    3081             except KeyError as err:
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 0
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 weather_anomaly['MONTH'][0]
> 2 print('The month with the greatest temperature anomaly is ',  weather_anomaly['MONTH'].values[0], 'of the year ',
> weather_anomaly['YEAR'].values[0], ' with a difference of ',
> weather_anomaly['diff'].values[0])
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py
> in **getitem**(self, key)
> 851
> 852         elif key_is_scalar:
> --> 853             return self._get_value(key)
> 854
> 855         if is_hashable(key):
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py
> in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
> 959
> 960         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
> --> 961         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
> 962         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
> 963
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py
> in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    3080
> return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)    3081             except
> KeyError as err:
> -> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err    3083     3084         if tolerance is not None:
>
> KeyError: 0

Nothing explaining comes up.
Fortunately the solution of this proplem is easy:

```
weather_anomaly['MONTH'].values[0]
```

So the final Question is despite data['DATE'] and monthly_data['abs_diff'] are both pandas.*Series* objects why weather_anomaly['abs_diff'][0] does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your original DataFrame has an index column with incrementing integers, so in your first example it so happens that `data['DATE'][0]` and `data['DATE'].iloc[0]` return the same result.

But after you select a specific row with the `max()` condition, the new DataFrame `weather_anomaly` contains only one row **which keeps its original index** which may not be zero.

Therefore, in order to select the first row of `weather_anomaly`, you need to either use `.iloc[0]` or `reset_index()` and use `[0]`.

I advise you print your DataFrames and you will clearly see how the index column behaves.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR  The reason is that the index of `weather_anomaly['MONTH']` is not normal integer.

> After some data manipulation i created a new DataFrame `monthly_data` with these indexes: MONTH TAVG YEAR temp_celsius ref_temp diff abs_diff

```py
weather_anomaly = monthly_data.loc[monthly_data['abs_diff'] == monthly_data['abs_diff'].max()]
```

As you stated above, The index of `monthly_data` is not integer. After doing operation on `monthly_data` to get `weather_anomaly`. The index of `weather_anomaly` is like `monthly_data`.

If you want to locate Series by integer, you can use [pandas.Series.iloc()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html). In your example,

```py
weather_anomaly['MONTH'].iloc[0]
```